# Histogram Issue in spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
+----+----+--------+
| Id | M1 |  trx   |
+----+----+--------+
| 1  | M1 | 11.35  |
| 2  | M1 | 3.4    |
| 3  | M1 | 10.45  |
| 2  | M1 | 3.95   |
| 3  | M1 | 20.95  |
| 2  | M1 | 25.55  |
| 1  | M1 |  9.95  |
| 2  | M1 | 11.95  |
| 1  | M1 |  9.65  |
| 1  | M1 | 14.54  |
+----+----+--------+
```

With the above dataframe I should be able to generate a histogram as below using the below code.

```scala
val (Range,counts) = df
    .select(col("trx"))
    .rdd.map(r => r.getDouble(0))
    .histogram(10)
// Range: Array[Double] = Array(3.4, 5.615, 7.83, 10.045, 12.26, 14.475, 16.69, 18.905, 21.12, 23.335, 25.55)
// counts: Array[Long] = Array(2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

`counts` contains the number of elements in each range.

But how to get the sum of the elements, `sum(trx)`, in each range like:

`sumOfTrx: Array[Long] = Array(7.3,0,19.6,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,25.55)`.

Comment: Pleas read how to post and how to edit on stack. I'll edit your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you built a histogram over the `trx` column and you want to get the sum of the values within each range.

What we can do is define a `UDF` that returns the index of the range given the value of the `trx` column. Then, we can use `groupBy` to compute what you want. The, a few manipulations will allow us to get the Array you want.

```scala
// getting the histogram
val (ranges, counts) = df
    .select("trx").rdd.map(_.getDouble(0))
    .histogram(10)

// the UDF I was referring to
val rangeIndex = udf((x : Double) => ranges.lastIndexWhere(x >= _))

// Summing the elements and building a map that associates indices to sums
val sumMap = df
    .withColumn("rangeIndex", rangeIndex('trx))
    .groupBy("rangeIndex")
    .agg(sum('trx))
    .rdd.map(x=> x.getAs[Int]("rangeIndex") -> x.getAs[Double]("sum(trx)") )
    .collectAsMap

// Building the array
ranges.indices.map(i => sumMap.getOrElse(i, 0d)).toArray
// res: Array[Double] = Array(7.35, 0.0, 19.6, 33.75, 0.0, 14.54, 0.0, 20.95, 0.0, 0.0, 25.55)
```

Comment: HI Oli,This is 99 % percent working. Thanks for that. the count of ranges.indices.map(i => sumMap.getOrElse(i, 0d)).toArray is 11. Is there any way to make this 10 (same as that of counts array)

Comment: This worked.!!!!! Thanks a lot Oli!!!!!!!!! This is a gem!!!!!

Comment: Yes.I have given ranges.dropRight(1) and then val rangeIndex = udf((x : Double) => rangeArray.lastIndexWhere(x >= _))

Comment: But your approach was awesome. Thanks for that. Do you have any possible solution for   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59224388/histogram-doing-it-in-a-parallel-way

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the answer with your comment. I have an answer for your other question, let me write it down ;)

Comment: Hi @Oli , Would you be able to advice on the pivot solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509684/pivot-in-spark-scala

Comment: I see that someone answered. Do you still need help?

Comment: Hi @Oli , Would you be able to advice  on the issue here ??? Thanks for all your previous support ... :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211108/finding-percentile-in-spark-scala-in-dynamic-way